# Returning a nested hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap, nested

I have the two following `HashMaps`where `Student` is an object I created and has the format `Student(String, String)`

```
static HashMap<String, Student> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
static HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Student>> finalHashMap = new HashMap<>();
```

I created the following `Students` and added them to `hashMap` with the `firstName` as the `Key`

```
Student st1 = new Student("julian", "rogers");
Student st2 = new Student("jason", "Smith");

hashMap.put("julian", st1);
hashMap.put("jason", st2);
```

Then I added `hashMap` to `finalHashMap` with the first letter of `firstName` as the `key`

```
finalHashMap.put("j", hashMap);
```

How can I return the hashmap with the key `j`?

I tried creating a new hashmap and used `get()` but it did not work. I get a `null pointer exception`

```
static HashMap<String, Student> hashMapTemp = new HashMap<>();
hashMapTemp.putAll(finalHashMap.get('j'));

for (String key : hashMapTemp.keySet())
{
    System.out.println(key + " " + hashMapTemp.get(key));
}
```

OUTPUT

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.HashMap.putAll(Unknown Source)
```

Note: I tried using `put()` and also got the same error.

Comment: Where do you get a NPE?

Comment: Why are you adding the results to `hashMapTemp` instead of just saying `for (String key : finalHashMap.get("j"))`?

Comment: As a note, it would probably be easier to parse things like this in the future if you posted it as a self-contained class to demonstrate the problem rather than a bunch of code snippets.

Answer (score 2):

`hashMapTemp.putAll(finalHashMap.get('j'));`

I think this should be :

`hashMapTemp.putAll(finalHashMap.get("j"));`

Your key in `finalHashMap` is a String, not a Character.

Answer (score 0):

```
hashMapTemp.putAll(finalHashMap.get('j'));
```

This line is kind of odd, you look for a character instead of a string (as you defined).
Consider using `static HashMap<Character, Student> finalHashMap = new HashMap<>()`

Answer (score -1):

```
public static HashMap<String, Student> find(String key, HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Student>> dataMap) {
    HashMap<String, Student> result = null;
    for (String s : dataMap.keySet()) {
        if (s.equalsIgnoreCase(key)) {
            result = dataMap.get(s);
            break;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

And then just call that method like this:

```
HashMap<String, Student> result = find("j", finalHashMap);
```

Comment: What's the point of using a HashMap, which provides an O(1) lookup method if, to find a value based on a key, you iterate on all the keys until you find the one you want, making it O(n)?